# jQuery - replace an element in a set (collection)

Tags: jquery

```
// jQuery 2.2.2

var set = $('<p></p><b></b><i></i>');
set.filter('b').replaceWith('<a></a>');
console.log( set );
```

I would expect `<b>` to be changed to an `<a>` element, but that is **not the case**.

How can one replace an element if not by using `filter` and then `replaceWith` ?

---

*(the element `<a>` which is to replace `<b>` has events)*

Comment: `filter()` returns a new jQuery object. `replaceWith()` returns a new jQuery object *containing the elements that were removed*. You're ignoring both these return values, so you're still operating on your original set.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - yes, filter returns a **new** one. then how can you replace it in a manner where you pick the same element instead of creating a new one? the selector part is the issue (the filtering)

Comment: Well this is odd.... my fiddle works, but it fails in the SO editor. https://jsfiddle.net/kqL0awot/.  @vsync you probably have enough rep to see my deleted answer.  Not to turn the question on you, but any idea why it works in fiddle but not editor? :P

Comment: You need to place a detailed sample of the html, then write what your expected results should be using jquery

Comment: @Patriotec - no I do not need to do that. I cannot post 1000 lines of dynamic content, it's illogical.

Comment: @JosephMarikle - of course it works in the jsfiddle, because it's very different than what I was asking. You are first placing the set in a container in a real DOM fragment, and then using `find`, which is completely different scenario. imagine you cannot do that.

Comment: @vsync Why don't you implement a map function instead of `replaceWith`? Might not be *pretty*, but atleast it will work.

Comment: @vsync why is find unacceptable?  It's in an isolated fragment.  What particularly is wrong with an approach that uses find instead of filter?

Comment: @JosephMarikle - because that doesn't replace the element in the set. is you do `console.log(set)` at the end, it will still look the same.

Comment: @vsync Yes.  You would have to utilize the document fragment at that point as evidenced by my appending the document fragment to the body.  In the end, the document fragment is also a collection of nodes.  Unless this is an incomplete minimal example, the fragment should work in most cases that the node collection would.

Comment: @vsync Here's an alternative, but again, it doesn't work in the stackoverfow editor and I don't know why. https://jsfiddle.net/kqL0awot/2/

Comment: @JosephMarikle - ok this works - https://jsfiddle.net/fnrfad9g/1/  it's not the best solution, and feels awkward, but works

Comment: @vsync at this point, wouldn't it better to do this? https://jsfiddle.net/go87d7oa/1/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - yes, it might be. it's not "simple" but it is less code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`replaceWith` docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

> As of jQuery 1.9, `.after()`, `.before()`, and `*.replaceWith()` always return the original unmodified set. Attempting to use these methods on a *node without a parent has no effect*— that is, neither the set nor the nodes it contains are changed.

This is exactly the case in your question: the set doesn't have a parent.

A quick test showed that `replaceAll` doesn't help either — it also requires the set to have a parent.

One possible solution is to do a textual replacement (on HTML level).

Another solution is to artificially create a parent, e.g. using `wrapAll`, for example:

```
var set = $('<p></p><b></b><i></i>');
set = set.wrapAll('<div></div>').parent();
set.children('b').replaceWith('<a></a>');
set = set.children();
console.log( set ); // p, a, i
```

Or combining three lines in one (arguable what's more readable):

```
var set = $('<p></p><b></b><i></i>');
set = set.wrapAll('<div></div>').parent().children('b').replaceWith('<a></a>').end().children();
console.log( set ); // p, a, i
```

---

Another alternative is to use `map` instead of `replaceWith`:

```
var set = $('<p></p><b></b><i></i>');
set = set.map(function(){
    return $(this).is('b') ? $('<a></a>').get() : this;
})
console.log( set ); // p, a, i
```

Comment: please delete your poor answer

Comment: @vsync, I've allowed myself to edit and restore the answer after some research. A very nice question, seems trivial and in fact it isn't.

Comment: It is in fact a very difficult situation. been doing jQuery for 10 years and I cannot recall such a situation before. Check my answer :)

Comment: you could have just wrapped it with a shorter string `<p>`, also in jQuery there is no need to close the tag, and also, it's much faster to use `find` instead of children, since children use `find` internally.  and last, this is longer than my solution :p

Comment: Thanks for the information — I'm not very good in JavaScript/jQuery in fact. But intuition told me that `children()` must be faster because it operates on one level only, now I learned that it was wrong. I've included one more possibility with `map`, just for completeness.

Comment: Actually this wouldn't work since you will loose all the jquery data and events bound on the element `<a>` which is to replace `<b>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var set = $('<p></p><b></b><i></i>');
```

#### Via plugin:

```
$.fn.replaceInSet = function(selector, replacement){
    if( replacement instanceof jQuery )
        replacement = replacement[0];

    return this.map(function(){
        return $(this).is(selector) ? replacement : this;
    });
}
```

#### Usage:

```
set = set.replaceInSet('b','a') // MUST assign the result to "set"!
```

<del>Currently the only way I found to solve this is by doing this:</del>

#### OR:

```
// the set of elements

set = $('<p>')            // create a fake element container
  .append(set)            // move the set inside it
  .find('b')              // now "find" could be used
  .replaceWith('<a>')     // replace the found element
  .end()                  // go back to the "p"
  .contents();            // fetch the set again

console.log(set) // will now include `<a>` and not `<b>`
```